# Having an error org.hibernate.HibernateException. The error is in the init method (while running the application as java app.)

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, maven

Mvn clean and Mvn install are successful without warnings and errors.The files hibernate.cfg.xml and App.java are:

The error from console during initialization is:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1797)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1755)
    at com.icdab.www.icdab_first.App.init(App.java:33)
    at com.icdab.www.icdab_first.App.main(App.java:76)
```

Hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory> 
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver.class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">system</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="hiberante.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>    
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>   
    <mapping class="com.icdab.www.icdab_first.CompundKey" /> 
    <mapping class="com.icdab.www.icdab_first.Customer" />
    <mapping class="com.icdab.www.icdab_first.Employee" />
    <mapping class="com.icdab.www.icdab_first.EventPlan" />
    <mapping class="com.icdab.www.icdab_first.EventPlanLine" />
    <mapping class="com.icdab.www.icdab_first.EventRequest" />
    <mapping class="com.icdab.www.icdab_first.Facility" />
    <mapping class="com.icdab.www.icdab_first.Location" />
    <mapping class="com.icdab.www.icdab_first.ResourceTbl" />

</session-factory>  
</hibernate-configuration>
```

App.java:

```
package com.icdab.www.icdab_first;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session; 
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration; 
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder; 
/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    private SessionFactory factory;
    private void init(){
        System.out.println("in init");
        Configuration config = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                /*.addAnnotatedClass(CompundKey.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Customer.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Employee.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(EventPlan.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(EventPlanLine.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(EventRequest.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Facility.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Location.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(ResourceTbl.class) */;

        // learn why did you use the annotatedclass and configuration.
          ServiceRegistry registry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
          factory=config.buildSessionFactory(registry);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void persistAnnotatedLists(){
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession(); 
        session.beginTransaction();
        Customer customer = new Customer(); 
        customer.setAddress("address123");
        customer.setCity("lansing");
        customer.setContact("1632 ne ave");
        customer.setCustname("john");
        customer.setCustno("1234");
        customer.setInternal("internal");
        customer.setPhone(122345679);
        customer.setState("OR");
        customer.setZip(97654);

        List<EventRequest> ers = new ArrayList<EventRequest>();


        ers.add(new EventRequest(123,new Date(92,5,1),new Date(91,5,1),new Date(93,5,1),"av",123,456,124));
        ers.add(new EventRequest(1234,new Date(92,5,2),new Date(91,5,2),new Date(93,5,2),"av",124,457,125));
        customer.setEventrequests(ers);
        session.save(customer); 

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        System.out.println("done persist");
    }
    private void retrieveList(){
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction(); 

        List list = session.createQuery("from com.icdab.www.icdab_first.Customer").list();

        for (Object object : list) {
            System.out.println("** List items: "+object);
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        System.out.println("Done retrieve");
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        App app = new App();
        app.init();
        app.persistAnnotatedLists();
        app.retrieveList();
    }
}
```

And the project structure is:

[image: the hibernate.cfg.xml is in src/main/Resources]

Comment: You have a typo `<property name="hiberante.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>`
it should be `hibernate`, not `hiberante`

Comment: Also make sure to keep your maven structure in lowercase. You should rename your 'Resources' folder to 'resources'.